# Non-normal extension of Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions, normal-extension

The counterexamples of normal extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ that I could find are basically all in the form of $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{\alpha})$ (with $x^n - \alpha$ being its minimal polynomial; and the minimal polynomial has complex roots, so doesn't split in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{\alpha})$).

I wonder if there is example such that the extension $E/\mathbb{Q}$ that is both non normal, and also contains complex numbers.

Any hint of how to find such extension would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use a single non-real cube (or $n$th) root of an integer $\alpha$. That is $\Bbb{Q}$-isomorphic to your $E$, so cannot be normal either. Or a field like $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i})$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$, with $\omega$ a complex cubic root of unity, is not normal and contains no real complex numbers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen is possible that an extension contains  and still being non-normal?

Comment: Yes, if course it can $\mathbb{}(i,\sqrt[3]2)$ is nonnormal (it does not contain all cubic roots of $2$), and contains $i$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes sure. I dunno why I previously somehow assumed that $\zeta_3$ could be generated by $(i, \sqrt[3]{2})$. Thank you!